# Reactjs - Facebook SDK login button not showing up the second time

Tags: reactjs, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using the following button and in a reactjs component. This component is called from react-router. Everything works fine if I call the page directly http://x.x.x.x/#/FBLogin.

But when I use a [router](https://github.com/rackt/react-router) The button does not show up?

```
  <Route name="app" path="/" handler={App}>
    <Route name="login" path="/FBLogin" handler={Login}/>
  </Route>

Router.run(routes, function (Handler) {
  React.render(<Handler/>, document.body);
});
```

I Chrome Inspector / React the div is in the DOM and looks the same in both cases.

```
    render(){
    return (      
      <div>
        <div className="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="1" data-size="large" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="false"></div>

      </div>
    );
  } // Render
```

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try calling [FB.XFBML.parse](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse) after rendering. It will check for Social Plugins on the whole page. I would suggest using your own Login Button in combination with [FB.login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/) instead. That way, you will not have all those problems.

I wrote a blogpost about that some time ago, if you need more information about dealing with FB.login in a good way: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/